# Random sleeping time in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

In R selenium it is possible to set a time sleep like this:

```
Sys.sleep(15)
```

How is it possible to set a random time? In python it is like this:

```
time.sleep(random.uniform(3.5,6.9))
```

Comment: Why don't you try the same way in R?

Comment: What is wrong with `Sys.sleep(runif(1, 3.5, 6.9))`?

Comment: @RHertel I didn't use the 1. Thank that is the answer for me

Answer (score 7):

`Sys.sleep(sample(1:10, 1))`

Should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

In Java Selenium 2.x, you can use `Sleeper.sleepTight(randomDurationInMS)`.  You probably have access to the same Sleeper class in your R bindings.

I think Selenium 3.0 (when it finally comes out) will get rid of that class though, but maybe something will replace it.